How to search in relationship?
I have a relationship "jobs" in the User model:
public function jobs(): HasMany
{
   return $this->hasMany(Job::class);
}

One user can have multiple jobs - or none.
I want to search also in the relation "jobs", for the title...
$users = User::with(['jobs'] => function($query) {
   $query->when(request()->has('search'), function($query) {
      $query->orWhere('title', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%');
   });
})->where(function($query) {
   if (request()->has('search')) {
      $query->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%'); // here can be added multiple fields to search from users table
   }
})
->paginate(10);

Is not searching in the "jobs" relationship.
I was trying also with "whereHas" - but it will show only the users that have jobs, like I said there are users that have no jobs...and I want them to be displayed.
How can I do this?
UPDATE
I think I found something ... using orWhereHas:
$users = User::with(['jobs'])
->where(function($query) {
   if (request()->has('search')) {
      // here can be added multiple fields to search from users table
      $query->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%'); 
    
      // here search in the relationship (if it exists)
      $query->orWhereHas('jobs', function($query) {
         $query->orWhere('title', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%'); 
     }); 
  }  
})
->paginate(10);


You can use orWhereHas('relation')  to perform any action on relational table. like below :
$users = User::with(['jobs'])
->where(function($query) {
   if (request()->has('search')) {
      // here can be added multiple fields to search from users table
      $query->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%'); 
    
      // here search in the relationship (if it exists)
      $query->orWhereHas('jobs', function($query) {
         $query->orWhere('title', 'like', '%' . request('search') . '%'); 
     }); 
  }  
})
->paginate(10);

